# Facebook Graph API: (#100) The After Cursor specified exeeds the max limit supported by this endpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm playing about with Facebook's graph api and I was wanting to learn more about the cursor pagination they use.

My access token `<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_ID>` if of type https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens

The post in which I am trying to access does not belong to me but is public (it's a random page that posts funny memes and gets thousands of comments).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<MY_POST_ID>/comments?access_token=<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_ID>
```

This returns a small list which is what I wanted. I however would like to transverse this list. Here is the result of the get request.

```
{
  ...// comments above here.
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "<BEFORE_ID>",
      "after": "<AFTER_ID>"
    },
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<MY_POST_ID>/comments?access_token=<MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_ID>&pretty=1&limit=25&after=<AFTER_ID>"
}
```

I paste in the `"next"` url, I however am met with the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) The After Cursor specified exeeds the max limit supported by this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "<FBTRACE_ID>"
   }
}
```

Anyone know what's up?

*I've replaced the actual id's of `<MY_POST_ID>` etc. if you didn't figure that out already.*

Comment: Use the cursors instead of next link

Comment: These auto-generated links should not lead to errors. If a specific endpoint has a maximum limit value, then the API should correctly take this into account when generating those links. Suggest you file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @WizKid The next link includes a cursor?

Comment: @CBroe Been confirmed already https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1772936312959430/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1772936312959430/

It's a bug that is currently under fixing.